# Debugger for Firefox not working in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, firefox, vscode-debugger, mozilla

OS: Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

I am trying to debug Angular/TypeScript code using VS Code in Firefox. I am encountering these two errors:

> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6000

When I install Firefox from Snap, I receive the following error:

> your firefox profile cannot be loaded. it may be missing or inaccessible

However, when I install Firefox from Flatpak, the above error doesn't occur.

Here is my launch.json configuration for debugging with VS Code and Firefox:

**launch.json**

```
{
    "name": "Launch Firefox",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "firefox",
    "url": "http://localhost:4200",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are likely using a firefox added by Snap.  Snap needs an extra configuration in your launch.json to indicate a tmp dir it can use.

Add `"tmpDir": "/some/folder/of/yours/with/write/perms"`

Note, this folder should probably be in your home directory.  I used `${HOME}/tmp` and create a `tmp` dir in my home directory.

Answer was found on [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409069/unable-to-launch-firefox-debugger-from-vscode-your-firefox-profile-cannot-be-lo)